# Anchor tag on Datatable column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

Anchor tag on field column .

How do i add a anchor tag along with title in datatable .

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
  debugger
    $('#TableId').DataTable(
    {
        //"columnDefs": [
        //    { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] },
        //    {
        //        "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",

        //        "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        //    },
        //],
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
            'width': '1%',
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
        }],
        "language":
            {
                "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
            },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":
            {
                "url": "/TicketTemplate/GetData",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "JSON"
            },
        "columns": [
                   { "data": '' },
                    { "data": "CreatedDate" },
                    { "data": "Title" },
                     //{
                     //    //"data": "Title",
                     //    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                     //        //return '<a href=\"' + Title + '\">' + Title + '</a>';
                     //        return '<a href="' + Title + '">' + data + '</a>';
                     //    }
                     //},
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Email" },
                    { "data": "AssignTo" },
                    { "data": "Status" }                  
        ]




    });
});
```

Here in the above code in the case of "Title" it must be an a anchor tag..

so any suggestions??

Here is the table:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" id="chkall" data-set="#sample_2.checkboxes" onclick="Selectallcheckbox()" />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th> Date Created </th>
            <th> Title </th>
            <th> User Name </th>
            <th> User Email </th>

            <th>Assigned To </th>
            <th> Status </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var itm in Model.TicketList)

        {
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>
                    <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" />
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="center"> @itm.CreatedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") </td>
                <td>
                    @*<a href="#" onclick="AppDetails(@itm.Id)">@itm.Title</a>*@
                    <a href="/TicketTemplate/AppDetails/@itm.Id">@itm.Title</a>
                </td>
                <td> @itm.Name </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"> @itm.Email  </a>
                </td>

                <td> @itm.AssignTo </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-sm label-warning"> @itm.Status </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

How do i show the title bar along with anchor tag??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
"columns": [
            {
             "name": "Name",
             "render": function (data, type, row) {
                   return "<a href=" + row.myURL+ "/"+ row.id+ "  
                   class='_myCkass' id=" + row.myID + ">" + row.fieldMark + "
                           </a>";
                }
            },
            { "data": "CreatedDate" },
            //Rest field
           ],
```

Comment: In the Title column must be a anchor tag and url is like /TicketTemplate/AppDetails/@itm.Id

Comment: here is the url.../TicketTemplate/AppDetails/@itm.Id

Comment: The anchor tag is not coming

Comment: Sir some one telling me in columnDefs

Comment: here is the code:{
              targets: 2,
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  if (type === 'display') {
                      data = '<a href="/TicketTemplate/AppDetails/' + data.id + '">' + data + '</a>';
                  }

                  return data;
              }
          }

Comment: can you tell me in anchor tag how do i send the id means /TicketTemplate/AppDetails/@itm.Id

Comment: Bro u r not understanding d code. I have already mentioned in my code row.Id.  And in myURL u just need to attach ur controller and action method separated by forward slash. Whill u click it will call to respective method with d id value.

Comment: in  row.id i am getting null

Comment: how to get the particular id of that row??

Comment: you just tell me in datecreated output is coming just like /Date(1489580817457)/

Comment: Do like this, href= "/TicketTemplate/AppDetails"+ row.Id + " It will bind respective Id to respective row. If ur model class have "ID" field, then change in data table to row.ID. the field name should b same other wise it won't work.

Comment: you just tell me in datecreated how to solve please??

Comment: but tell me in the datecreated what should i do??

Comment: Man u need to hire me for that. How could someone expect everything without writing anything

Comment: but tell me in the datecreated what should i do??

Comment: Check with ur DB. If it has date value then it should render properly. Otherwise u just need to convert to Date and bind. Check how to convert string to date. If it's help u plz don't forget to mark as answer

Comment: i am getting datetime format in model and render that same things but the issue is on /Date(1489580817457)/

Comment: { "data": "CreatedDate" }, It should bind d correct date. See ur field value should b match with ur model value

Answer (score 0):

I was using jinja and just had to include `data-href` on tr.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable tbody tr').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).data('href');
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
          $(this).wrapInner('<a href="' + href + '"></a>');
        });    
    });
});
```

This code adds anchor tags for every td and works perfectly fine with clicks and right clicks.